# How can I exit from my app?

Tags: java, android

How can I exit from my app?

I want that when the user will clicked on the button,
the app will exit completely, I saw any answers about it, but they took the app to backend,

I want to exit completely

Comment: Please explain what "exit completely" means in technical terms. Also, please explain why the user would want your app to "exit completely".

Comment: I saw a video on youtube once of one of the android devs going off about the fact that an "exit" button is not needed in any android app. Once the app no longer has focus and is in the background the garbage collector will recover the resources if needed.

Comment: The most recent Android version may not kill the app even when you call exit or end all threads.

Comment: yes I understand your's answers, the task for me is to exit from the app, and I asked this question to know if it's realy possible to exit completely but now from your's answers I'm understanding that it's not possible and it's not use, do I understand you well? the exit to bakend it's realy enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this method you have can call `exit()` function anywhere and get exit from the app. so For closing an app at any point use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag in Intent & then system.exit();

NOTE : I think in way it will not break the Android Life cycle

**In a place where you need to execute EXIT from the app**

```
public void exit() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class).
    setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).putExtra(EXIT_FLAG, true));
}
```

**MainActivity.onCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXIT_FLAG, false)) {
        if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0) {
            finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use,

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

then according to the Doc.

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in
>   the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used
>   when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from
>   an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used
>   the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own
>   task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other
>   activities of the second application, all of those should be removed
>   from the original task as part of the task switch.
>
> Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the
>   previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying
>   to do so.

for more info about the Android docs, take a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: this code exit completly from app? or take it to the backend? thank you!